# Using A type to define unpacked args from a method

Tags: python, type-hinting

say I have a type:

```
class MyType(Generic[T, U]):
    def foo(self, *args: T) -> U:
        pass

m = MyType[tuple[int, bool], str]
```

I want to be able to provide the args like:

```
m.foo(1, True)
```

instead of

```
m.foo((1, True))
```

Is there any way to do this in a method using the generic, so if I have a type that is multiple args I can unpack them in a method?

I see I can use:

```
P = ParamSpec("P")
```

but then I'd want to put a type constraint on the P.args so that it was equal to T.

Answer (score 1):

`TypeVarTuple` is what you want: It collects an unspecified number of type arguments and allows you to unpack it later.

<sub>(playground links: [mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=bbe7df0ac2d3ec8888a0449fb069b335), [Pyright](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=MYGwhgzhAECyCeAVeAHApgbQFSIgGmgFUBdALgFgAoK6W6AEzQDNomB7NgCgjRCYKxgATgHMIpaDggBKaAFoAfEQqU6a6ADotVKgFtoAXjhJUmAJYA7AC4EARhxAEIVocU7SdlIWgBuaMCAA%2BlamnLoa7FwAjASIQgCuaNIelEA))</sub>

```py
class MyType[*Ts, U]:

    def foo(self, *args: *Ts) -> U:
        ...
```

```py
m = MyType[int, bool, str]()    # No extra brackets

reveal_type(m.foo(1, True))     # mypy => str
                                # Pyright => str
```

In Python 3.10 or older:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
from typing_extensions import TypeVarTuple, Unpack

Ts = TypeVarTuple('Ts')
U = TypeVar('U')

class MyType(Generic[*Ts, U]):

    def foo(self, *args: Unpack[Ts]) -> U:
        ...
```

Or, with `ParamSpec`:

<sub>(playground links: [mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=001d350e2f03e32682605b3bbe52a0c6), [Pyright](https://pyright-play.net/?pythonVersion=3.12&strict=true&code=MYGwhgzhAECyCeAVeAHApgbQFRYAoBpoBVAXQC4BYAKGujugBM0AzaZge3YAoI0RnCWMACcA5hDLRcAOhHjBWANYB3ORKnSVagJTQAtAD5ilKvTPRpl6tQC20ALxwkqTBgCWAOwAuhAEacQEkIIL2ESLm1rKmE0ADc0MBAAfS8XLhtpDm4ARkJEYQBXNG1IqiA))</sub>

```py
class MyType[**P, U]:

    def foo(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> U:
        ...
```

```py
m = MyType[[int, bool], str]()  # One extra pair
```